# In a BOINC project, how are responses checked for accuracy?

Tags: distributed-systems

More specifically, how can project administrators be sure that the answers they receive from nodes are correct and not just simple calculations performed quickly and submitted as complete work units? As various cheating scandals have shown, people are not above stooping to low levels to get to the top of project points tables...

Comment: [boinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Open_Infrastructure_for_Network_Computing) berkeley open infrastructure for network computing

Comment: How is this a computer science question, and not just a question about how Boinc is implemented? Do you mean to ask "How can a distributed system like BOINC, i.e. where the stakeholder does not control all clients, ensure correctness?" or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the checking that is performed by the BOINC platform to avoid cheating is to send the same work units to different users, and then verify that the results are the same.

Comment: That does not protect against cabals, of course.